# How can I hide my drop-down menu option(s)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown-menu, **Class View** is my default option.

[image]

When I clicked on the arrow, I have this

[image]

---

I tried to hide **Class View** option, and set **Geary, Mia** as my default option. I couldn't get it to hide.

---

## HTML

```
<div class="row cb-btns-row " style="background-color:white;">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-1" tabindex="1">   <span>Class View </span>

            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a id="class-view" href="#">Class View</a>

                </li>
                <li><a id="student#1" class="student" href="#">Geary, Mia</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

## JS

```
// dropDown Menu 
function dropDown(el) {

    this.dd = el;
    this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
    this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
    this.val = '';
    this.index = -1;
    this.initEvents();
}


dropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents: function () {
        var obj = this;

        obj.dd.on('click', function (event) {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            return false;
        });

        obj.opts.on('click', function () {
            var opt = $(this);
            obj.val = opt.text();
            obj.index = opt.index();
            obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
        });
    },
    getValue: function () {
        return this.val;
    },
    getIndex: function () {
        return this.index;
    }
}

$(function () {

    var dd = new dropDown($('#dd'));

    $(document).click(function () {

        $('.wrapper-dropdown-1').removeClass('active');

    });

    var $student = $('.student');
    var $classView = $('.classView');
    
    $classView.hide(); // I tried
    

  
});
```

---

## What I have

Live Result  = http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/8cnz2r67/1/show

Live Code = http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/8cnz2r67/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistaken the jquery selector for `class-view` which is id and not class. So put `#` instead of `.` and then hide it's parent `li` using `closest()`. Also to set the default value, set `student`'s text in first span under `.wrapper-dropdown-1`

```
var $student = $('.student');
 var $classView = $('#class-view');//its id and not class

 $classView.closest('li').hide(); //hide parent li
 //set default as student
 $('.wrapper-dropdown-1').find('span:first').text($student.text());
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8cnz2r67/6/)**

Comment: Why do we need to use `closest('li')` ? why can't we hide it directly ? Just curious, thanks.

Comment: drop down has `li` list and inside `li` there are `<a>` tags. If you hide just `<a>` then there will be empty `li` and look like blank option. We need to hide `li` which is parent to first option and this `li` don't have any class or id to identify hence using `closest()` to find it.

Comment: Quick question for you, now `Class View` option is stuck in a hiding mode through out my application, how can I prevent that ? Can I use a `.off()` or anything similar to that ?

Comment: if you are not going to show it again in your application then use `.remove()` instead of `.hide()`

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that now.

Comment: Even after using `remove()` , my Class View is still gone everywhere elses through out my application, after I select any of my students.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem on jsfiddle and explain it

Answer (score 1):

Here a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8cnz2r67/9/

**Javascript**

```
dropDown.prototype = {
    //...
    setDefault: function(def) {
        this.placeholder.text(def)
    }
}
```

In the `document.ready`:

```
var dd = new dropDown($('#dd'));
dd.setDefault($(".default").text())
```

And just add a default class to the element that you wanna set to default.

Hope it helps you! ;)

Comment: Do I have to add `default` class into my HTML code ? Will it have any major effect on anything elses ? Just curious.

Comment: In this code, you should, because in javascript, you will use this class into `dd.setDefault`. But if you don't want to add a new class, just replace: `.default` with your `.student` class or your id `student#1`. It's the same! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try following by replacing

```
$classView.hide(); // I tried
```

with

```
$('.wrapper-dropdown-1').addClass('active');
$student.click();
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UsmanArshad87/qvmkjq0t/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but according to your fiddle `Class View` is still be an option, I want to hide it completely.